# ImportError: No module named 'nets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to convert trained_checkpoint  to final frozen model from the export_inference_graph.py script provided in tensorflow/models,but the following error results.
And yes,I have already setup $PYTHONPATH to "models/slim" but still I get this error,can someone help me out?

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/home/ishara/tensorflow_models/models:/home/ishara/tensorflow_models/models/slim
```

*****************************problem****************************************************************************

```
$sudo python3 object_detection/export_inference_graph.py  --input_type image_tensor  --pipeline_config_path = "ssd_inception_v2_pets.config"  --trained_checkpoint_prefix="output/model.ckpt-78543"  --output_directory="birds_inference_graph.pb"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/export_inference_graph.py", line 74, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/exporter.py", line 28, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 28, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'nets'
```

---

I have been struggling with this for days now,tried many solutions nothing work
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with tensorflow-gpu version.

Comment: what's your tensorflow version?

Comment: Its tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0)

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this kind of question without detailed instructions on exactly what you did and what happened. Here it looks like you are using a 3rd-party object-detection package, not Tensorflow alone?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at Protobuf Compilation at 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md
and set PYTHONPATH correctly, this is how I solved this for Windows

For Windows:

## From tensorflow/models/research/

Step1: `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

Step2:

```
set PYTHONPATH= <Path to 'research' Directory> ; <Path to 'slim' Directory>
```

For Eg:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\Guy\Desktop\models\research;C:\Users\Guy\Desktop\models\research\slim
```

Comment: This is a working solution. But I have to do it each time I restart the machine. It is not permanent. Any thoughts ?

Comment: No Soumya, till now there is no permanent solution for this. You have to do this each time you restart your machine. Maybe in future versions, this will get solved.

Comment: Does it make sense to add those variables to your conda enviroment? https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables

Comment: @SoumyaBoral the 'set' command will set it temporarily to make it permanent you have to modify the 'environment variables'

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 18 physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)**strong text**

```
cd models/research/slim/;
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

That's in case you've got downloaded or cloned your models directory.

Answer (score 5):

TF-Slim is available as tf.contrib.slim via TensorFlow 1.0, so you **don't** need to install it additionally if you used `pip install tensorflow`. You still need to do these 3 things:

1. Install the models library

   ```
   $ cd
   $ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models/
   ```
2. Add the `PYTHONPATH` to `.bashrc`

   ```
   $ cd
   $ vi .bashrc

   export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/${YOUR_USERNAME}/models/research/slim"
   ```
3. Add the models path to your script

   ```
   $ vi ${YOUR_SCRIPT}.py

   import sys
   sys.path.append('/home/${YOUR_USERNAME}/models/research/slim/')
   ```

After these 3 steps you're all set. Now you can import the TF nets like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import slim
from nets import inception_resnet_v2
```

Answer (score 3):

I did get the same error, because I had missed out to actually put the slim package into the tensorflow/models folder. The slim package is on
https://github.com/tensorflow/models

Answer (score 2):

encountered the slim error on windows and this solved my problem

. What I did was, I just copied the entire nets folder from slim directory to C:\Python\Python\Lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg (where I installed object_detection API). Then the error is completely gone.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed on newer versions of tensorflow, if you get it just update your tensorflow version.

Comment: It is happening in the latest tensorflow gpu version ( 1.9 ) also. However @Pawan's solution solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS:

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/username/models/research/slim:$PYTHONPATH`

Solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PYTHONPATH issue.

I would like to add to the existing answers, that if it's still not working for you and you use an Anaconda environment, use the Anaconda Prompt (in Admin mode) that comes with the distribution and not the system prompt of your OS. Set the PYTHONPATH within the Anaconda Prompt and run your commands from there.

Also the PYTHONPATH is reseted at each deactivation of the anaconda environment, including here a machine restart. So remember to set it again.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Jupyter Notebook and using Linux sys

download [tensorflow-models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models)

and then write this in your Notebook

`sys.path.append("/home/Roy/Downloads/models-master/research/slim/")`

I solved my problem with this

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by rebuilding protos go and check /models/research/object_detection/protos check for file center_net_pb2.py check all files if protos are generated if not generate manually by code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by rebuilding protos go and check /models/research/object_detection/protos check for file center_net_pb2.py check all files if protos are generated if not generate manually by code.Make sure you set your PYTHONPATH correctly first