# Error training object-detection model on Google Cloud ML Engine no module nets

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I get the following error when I start training the model on google cloud ml engine:

The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main "**main**", mod_spec) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/object_detection/model_tpu_main.py", line 30, in  from object_detection import model_lib File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 28, in  from object_detection import exporter as exporter_lib File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py", line 28, in  from object_detection.builders import model_builder File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 35, in  from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 28, in  from nets import inception_resnet_v2 **ImportError: No module named 'nets'**

Comment: It looks like nets is part of the `slim` library, see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1842. Can you try adding the path to the `slim` library to the `packages` parameter when submitting the job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'nets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030481/importerror-no-module-named-nets)